# SendKeys not working in Datagridview keydown event

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a Datagridview on my form with two columns. I only want the cells in the first column to be selected. So I'm using the datagridview's keydown event to capture the TAB and SHIFT+TAB. So if the first row is selected and the user presses tab, the second row will be selected instead of staying on the first row and selecting the second column's cell.

My if statement for the TAB key is working fine, but for some reason the SHIFT+TAB statement isn't. The cell above the currently selected cell isn't getting selected. Nothing happens.

```
Private Sub myGrid_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles myGrid.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab Then
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        SendKeys.Send("{DOWN}")
    End If

    If e.Modifiers = Keys.Shift AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab Then
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        SendKeys.Send("{UP}")
    End If
End Sub
```

The really weird thing though is if I add a messagebox into the statement it works.

```
If e.Modifiers = Keys.Shift AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab Then
    MsgBox("test")
    e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    SendKeys.Send("{UP}")
End If
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to redefine user experience? All users are used to the fact that up and down is moving, well, up and down, and tab is... sideways. It's like making a car run vertically instead of horizontally.

Comment: The two columns are "Question #" and "Score". When you select a row the rest of the information on the form changes to match the information for the selected question. I just want the user to only have to hit TAB once instead of twice to go down a row.

Comment: Why not leave a user with their default option - up/down?

Comment: The user can use up/down arrow keys if they want to. I'm just wanting the TAB key to go from column 0 : cell 0 to column 0 : cell 1 instead of column 0 : cell 0 to column 1 : cell 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help from @rheitzman I was able to see the main issue. The issue came from having the TAB and SHIFT+TAB in two different if statements. Here's my updated code:

```
Private Sub myGrid_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles myGrid.KeyDown
    Dim row As String = Me.myGrid.CurrentCellAddress.Y

    If e.Modifiers = Keys.Shift AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab Then
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        Me.myGrid.CurrentCell = Me.myGrid.Rows(row - 1).Cells(0)
        Me.myGrid.Rows(row - 1).Cells(0).Selected = True

    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab Then
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        Me.myGrid.CurrentCell = Me.myGrid.Rows(row + 1).Cells(0)
        Me.myGrid.Rows(row + 1).Cells(0).Selected = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: There is still a problem with this technique. The KeyDown event does not fire while the cell is in edit mode. i.e. If you edit a cell and press Tab the selection goes to the next cell and the KeyDown for the grid does not fire. I guess you would have to use and End or Leave event for the cell to control the next selection. Since Keycode isn't available you might have to stash the edited cells index somewhere to determine if you go down or up in the column. There may be a Cell KeyDown somewhere - I didn't see it.

Comment: I have the grid set to readonly. The grid is only there to display the number of questions and the scores that have been made to them. The user sets the score for the question with a drop down list and then I add the score to the grid. It's working like it should now and I'm a happy camper :)

Answer (score 0):

Sendkeys is a last, last resort...

How about something like this:

```
Private Sub dgv_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles dgv.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab Then
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        dgv.CurrentCell = dgv(0, dgv.CurrentCell.RowIndex + 1)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The Handles dgv.KeyDown is the override. A second check is needed in the same event for Shift.

Answer (score 0):

Tab and Shift+Tab are already handled by Windows Forms and DataGridView. They move the cell highlighter/selector move left(previous) and right(next). You'd have to create a class that inherits DataGridView and manually override their functionality to achieve what you want, then use that new class for your data grid.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.KeyDown

    Dim r As Integer = Me.DataGridView1.CurrentCellAddress.Y
    Dim f As Integer = Me.DataGridView1.CurrentCellAddress.X

    If e.Modifiers = Keys.Shift AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab Then
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        If 0 = r Then
            Me.DataGridView1.CurrentCell = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.RowCount - 1).Cells(f - 1)
            Me.DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.RowCount - 1).Cells(f - 1).Selected = True
        Else
            Me.DataGridView1.CurrentCell = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(r - 1).Cells(f)
            Me.DataGridView1.Rows(r - 1).Cells(f).Selected = True
        End If
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab Then
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        If DataGridView1.RowCount = (r + 1) Then
            Me.DataGridView1.CurrentCell = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(f + 1)
            Me.DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(f + 1).Selected = True
        Else
            Me.DataGridView1.CurrentCell = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(r + 1).Cells(f)
            Me.DataGridView1.Rows(r + 1).Cells(f).Selected = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```